# Troubleshooting "Permission denied" when attempting to connect to Redis from PHP script

Tags: php, redis, selinux

Port 6379 is open on the server, and I can successfully run `telnet localhost 6379` in SSH.

I tried both Predis/phpredis client library in PHP, but it still does not work:

- Predis gives "Permission denied" error when opening socket to 6379.
- phpredis gives "redis server went away".

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Problem solved, type:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

By default, SELinux does not allow Apache to make socket connections. More information can be found [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache).

Comment: Is this setting permanent? Or should it be added to a boot init script? Or etc file?

Comment: Thanks a ton for this question- answer. Hours saved! It might solve one more error I got while I was trying to run a c++ executable which also tried to open ports as well.

Comment: I tried with python redis client and got this problem and Its saved hours!!

Comment: To be keep the config across reboots use `-P` flag: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: Saved me so much time. Thanks!

Comment: So much useful even after 8 years.